# Grails spring security grant authorization based on login method

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have an application where a user should get access to different parts of the site based on 2  alternative login methods, one being the basic daoAuthentication and the other being a custom login method.

Both methods are there an works perfectly but im not sure how to go by to identfy how the user logged in.
ideally i would like to be able to create something that resembles the build in rules(IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED,IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY)
it would be great if i could just add in a IS_AUTHENTICATED_CUSTOM_AUTH somewhere.